# stdin no funciona muy bien

Tags: python-3.x

me gustara crear un programa que pregunte a x programa y este me conteste con una salida "sí" o "no", el caso es que cuando pongo en el terminal por ejemplo:

> ./x.out running | python3 y.py

./x.out era solo un ejemplo por lo que muy probablemente cambie de lenguaje de programación en el que este escrito
aqui dejo el codigo de x.py

```
import sys
import random
arg1 = sys.argv[1]
options = ["yes","no"]
if (arg1 == "running"):
    print(random.choice(options))
```

siempre devuelve "SE HA PRODUCIDO UN RESULTADO INESPERADO" de y.py que puedo hacer para corregir esta parte?

```
from sys import stdin

def main():
    for line in stdin:
        if line == "yes":
            print("PROGRAM RETURN YES")
        elif line == "no":
            print("PROGRAM RETURN NO")
        else:
            print("AN UNEXPECTED RESULT HAS OCCURRED")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Podrias imprimir la línea a ver que obtienes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que el primer programa manda un texto con un '\n' al final. Ese '\n' es parte de `line

La solución es eliminarlo usando `strip()`

El código corregido es:

```
from sys import stdin

def main():
    for line in stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == "yes":
            print("PROGRAM RETURN YES")
        elif line == "no":
            print("PROGRAM RETURN NO")
        else:
            print("AN UNEXPECTED RESULT HAS OCCURRED")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Demo

```
candid@gear:~/inter$ python3 x.py running|python3 y.py 
PROGRAM RETURN NO
```

Otra prueba:

```
candid@gear:~/inter$ echo "yes"|python3 y.py 
PROGRAM RETURN YES
candid@gear:~/inter$ echo "no"|python3 y.py 
PROGRAM RETURN NO
candid@gear:~/inter$ echo "quizas"|python3 y.py 
AN UNEXPECTED RESULT HAS OCCURRED
```